# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens :

Tags: php, pdo

I'am trying to insert in my two table at once

but i keep getting this error

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens :

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

try{
    if(sizeof($return['error'])==0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO circle_call_prefixes (circle, prefix)
                  VALUES (?,?)";
        $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $q ->execute(array('123', '123'));
        $Last_ID = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        $sql_table2 = "INSERT INTO circle_call_destinations 
          (autoNo,destination, source_circle) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $q -> execute(array($Last_ID, '123', '123'));

        $dbh->commit();
    }
```

what is the possible problem? thanks

Comment: can you check if $Last_ID getting you value?

Comment: I check it . . the value is zero (0)

Comment: try to replace $Last_id with any int 1 for example and test

Comment: i try that,  same error appear. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to run in both cases $sql, but should run in second case $sql_table2. This code should works:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

try{
    if(sizeof($return['error'])==0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO circle_call_prefixes (circle, prefix)
                  VALUES (?,?)";
        $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $q ->execute(array('123', '123'));
        $Last_ID = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        $sql_table2 = "INSERT INTO circle_call_destinations 
          (autoNo,destination, source_circle) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $q = $dbh->prepare($sql_table2);
        $q -> execute(array($Last_ID, '123', '123'));

        $dbh->commit();
    }
```